# Is the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n+1)^{1/2}}{n^2}$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For this question I am not really sure which test to use to determine this. I was thinking the comparison or limit comparison test but it doesn't seem to be working. I was wondering what the steps are to figure this out, and if it is the comparison test, how would you use it? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{n^2} \leq \dfrac{\sqrt{3n}}{n^2} = \dfrac{\sqrt3}{n^{3/2}}$$
Hence, the series $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{n^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sqrt3}{n^{3/2}} = \sqrt3 \zeta(3/2) < \infty$$

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering how you chose to compare it to (3n)^(1/2)?

Comment: @user138069: probably since $2n+1\le3n$ for $n\ge1$.

Comment: @user138069 Note that asymptotically we have $\dfrac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{n^2} \sim \dfrac{\sqrt{2n}}{n^2}$. Hence, we know that the $n^{th}$ term goes as $\dfrac1{n^{3/2}}$. All we need to do is to find the appropriate scale. Here it turns out to be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}}{n^2}\sim_\infty\sqrt2\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$
hence the given series is convergent by the asymptotic comparison with a convergent Riemann series.